# How to add a where class to find all records with datetime expiring in x days

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model with a datetime column that is the expire_at.

So I want to find all records that are expiring in 3 days.

```
def find_expring_in(days)
  Products.where(expiring_at: ???? )
end
```

Comment: check answer below. is it working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of range operator `..` to fetch all records that are expiring in 3 days

```
Products.where(expiring_at: Date.current..(Date.current + 3.days))
```